# How to print out a whole table in relational algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

I want to print out all the columns of a table which meet a certain criteria in another table. Is there a shorter way to do it than π(column1, column2, .... ,column8)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get you. You have some relation and wrap a projection of all the attributes around it? In this case you can just skip the projection.

```
R = {a1,..,an}
πa1,..,an(R) = R
```